# Increase or decrease values based on another value with diminishing returns

Tags: unity, c#

I'm making a village building type of game in Unity (using C#). Of course we have the classic villager who can chop trees. In my game I want the player to care about their villagers by making them more efficient at tasks that they do often and so losing a villager has a big impact on the efficiency for their village.

Take for example chopping trees. Villagers will have a TreeChopSpeed and TreeChopDamage value to them. The TreeChopSpeed is really the delay between playing the chop animation. So the lower this value the more efficient the villager is as the delay between chops is reduced. The TreeChopDamage is how much damage each chop does so the higher this value the more efficient the villager is.

I was thinking of making a TreeChopExperience variable and I would simply add to this value on each chop the villager does.

I'm not that experienced on the math side of things, but I was wondering if there was a way to use this TreeChopExperience value (that just keeps increasing) to calculate the TreeChopSpeed and TreeChopDamage with a way to tweak it to meet how quickly I'd want a villager to get to top efficiency but once I have that it would stay that way forever?

I would obviously cap both of those so they can't go too crazy.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I would look into `AnimationCurve` in Unity, you can edit a curve in the inspector, and then could do something like: `var treeChopSpeed = myCurve.Evaluate(myTreeChopExp) * myTreeChopSpeedBase` .

Comment: @Charly That's brilliant! Just watched a tutorial on these. Never thought about using it for other things but this seems perfect for this. Thank you!

Comment: If you've solved your problem with an animation curve, be sure to write up your solution as an Answer below.